# Jupyter Notebook working under conda base but not under virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, conda

I have created a virtual environment called "earthfault" and installed the jupyter notebook using `conda install jupyter`.
The installation is successful. When I try to start, I get a web browser opening up with `http://localhost:8888/tree` as adress but with blank page.

Jupyter notebook works fine under the base environment:

`D:\projects\conda activate`

`(base) D:\projects\jupyter notebook`

But when I try on the new virtual env :

`D:\projects\conda activate earthfault`

`(earthfault) D:\projects\jupyter notebook`

the page is blank.

I have tried without success:

- removing one day of the history of the browser
- adding the virtual env Scripts folder (`D:\bin\anaconda3\envs\earthfault\Scripts`) to the PATH
- copy pasting the URL (http://localhost:8888/?token=860f2a4a21eb39cd641b74682170814255e8b3abd82c1de2) into two other web browsers

I see on the command line that line appearing when I paste the URL in a browser:

`[I 15:07:21.628 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=64c5452fe53980acc1134f878f822076748204b9fed4fb60 (::1) 1.00ms`

Versions I use (successfully in base, unsuccessfully in earthfault):

- jupyter 1.0.0 (py37_7)
- python 3.7.0 (hea74fb7_0)

This is the `environment.yml` I use to create the virtual environment.

```
name: earthfault
dependencies:
  - numpy==1.15.1
  - pandas==0.23.4
  - matplotlib==2.2.3
  - xlrd==1.2.0
  - python==3.7.0
  - jupyter==1.0.0
  - jupyter_client==5.2.3
  - jupyter_console==5.2.0
  - pip:
    - xhtml2pdf==0.2.3
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the caches and cookies?

Comment: @AhmedHawary yes I have. Initially just removed one day. After your comment, I tried to remove all cookies and cache in the browser (Chrome). No success. I also tried to start in Incognito Mode, without success as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening jupyter notebook in base env and then changing env from there.  To do that you would need to install nb_conda package.  Here's the link to get it:
https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda

Comment: Thanks for this. It does work when I use nb_conda and create a new  notebook in the correct virtualenv. I can also switch kernels between virtualenv. Initial problem not yet identified but I will use this trick to continue working.

Comment: You're welcome.  You can work with virtual env directly as well but it is unduly cumbersome.  Check this:   (https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/)